# Android Contacts Backup (and Restore)

Tags: android, backup, contact-manager

Can anyone recommend a reliable Android (KitKat-compatible) contacts backup/restore tool that is able to **successfully** backup and restore the following *offline* contact:

```
First Name: Nikola
Last Name: Tesla
Group: Scientists
Company: Nikola's Laboratories
Title: Owner
Phone: (Laboratory) 111-111-1111
Phone: (Basement Office) *99 111-111-1111 x1111
Location: (Laboratory) 123 Electric Slide Row #1, Energy Village, BL 12345
Location: (Basement Office) 456 Light Lane, Volt Village, PA 12345-1234
Website: nikolatesla-ftw.org
Website: tesla-candy-store.com
Birthday: July 10, 1856
Notes:
    Electric conversation while drinking tea together  
    Dog's Name:
     Sparky
    Favorite Color:
     Electric-Orange
```

I have tried over a dozen backup/restore apps, import/export apps, web-apps, and other tools, and they all fail a "roundtrip" backup-restore process in one way or another.

Here are the common snags:

1. Unable to backup/restore the Group
2. Unable to handle custom multi-word *types* such as 'Basement Office' for phone numbers **and** locations
3. Unable to properly handle multi-line notes, notes that have lines that begin with spaces, or notes with blank lines
4. Unable to backup/restore all fields
5. Unable to handle multiple websites
6. Unable to handle all legal characters in phone numbers: `0-9 + * , ; ( )`
7. Unable to handle basic special characters in all fields, including: `# & $ : ' , + - _`
8. Unable to maintain order of multiple phone numbers or addresses
9. Unable to backup birthdate

The default Android contact export/import process supplied by Google (via their *Contacts* app) fails on multiple issues, including #1 and #2.

The following features would be nice, but are *not* required (in order of importance):

1. Backup/export to a human readable/editable format such as CSV, XML, or HTML
2. Gratis (free-of-charge)
3. Open-source

Note that all the contacts that need to be backed up are *offline* contacts, not Google contacts.  When they are restored, they should remain that way.

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: @Firelord  Recommendations that require root as well as recommendations that do not require root are both welcome.

Comment: You mention having tried a bunch of apps, and the "contact backup/restore process supplied by Google". Have you tried the most simple variant as well: Open the *contacts* app, hit *menu*, select "Import/Export", and then "Export to SD card" / "Import from SD card"? This process uses the standard VCard format, so you can check with all kinds of applications (including plain-text viewers) what has been backed up.

Comment: `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db` holds all the contacts and their details. Simply back it up, and when the time comes, restore that file, reboot, and all good. Backup `profile.db` because it also contains some related info, loose-ends. Everything related to Contacts is under those two files.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  I've tried the Android *contacts* app... it is the "supplied by Google" item I mentioned.   Unfortunately, it fails miserably.  It fails on at least snag #1 and #2.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks Firelord.  What database format are those files in?  What specific classes of data are in profile.db?  Where are the groups stored?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard maybe you should make that clear in your question as well; I wasn't sure whether you were referring to Google's cloud backup, others might even take that for granted here. As for Firelord's suggestion: that would require root, and it's an SQLite database you can easily explore e.g. using SQLiteMan – if you have root and thus can get your hands on it. Unfortunately, `adb backup` refuses to take care for that on most devices.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the details and request.  I've updated the question per your recommendation.

Comment: http://www.fjsoft.at/en/  Try MyPhoneExplorer.  You need USB debugging turned on, but that is simple.  You need to install the client on your phone and the main software on a PC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the term "offline" contact. If you don't want to [cook something up yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701727/extract-contact-list-in-vcf-format) and if you are able to do communication over the network, you can give synchronization via [CardDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDAV) a try.

I have good experiences with [DAVDroid](https://davdroid.bitfire.at/what-is-davdroid). It's a Free Software application that syncs contacts as well as calendars and tasks. It's very easy to set up and use.

[image]

For the server side, you can use, e.g. [Baïkal](https://github.com/netgusto/Baikal/) or [radicale](http://radicale.org/). You can self-host these on your local network if you don't want to set up anything on the Internet.  Both servers allow you to extract your contacts as vCards.

Restoring is then, at least in theory, as easy as [importing the vCard to your phone](https://code.google.com/p/vcardio/).

Comment: By *offline*, I mean not synced to any server.

Comment: I took a look at radicale, and it is python & designed for linux & Windows. On what platform(s) does Baikal run? Are there any DAVDroid-compatible servers that will run on an Android device?

Comment: Any thoughts on the above questions?

Comment: Baikal runs on PHP. I'm not aware of any implementation of a DAV server running on Android, but when I'm searching for "dav server android" I get a few results.