# Gratis Android manager for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, android, file-management, backup

I am looking for a gratis Windows app which allows me to access/control/backup & restore/file transfer my Android device.

That's it really; it sounds simple enough, but I have been searching online & can't find anything (at least, nothing gratis).

Please only recommend something which you have been using for some time & would recommend.

Comment: Related: *[MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client)* can do more than [described in this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/28007/185), see [related posts at our Android sister site](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=myphoneexplorer). Not being a Windows user, I haven't used it myself and thus cannot post it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

While there are several contenders in this category, I could have recommended all.

Here is one of them; [MoboMarket](http://www.mobomarket.net/forpc.html) (MoboRobo) . Since you want gratis you could go with  the Ads supported version, and it won't cost you a penny:)

> Enables you to easily manage multimedia files from your Android or iOS
>   based devices, back up important data, send SMSs and download new
>   apps, songs and themes

Screenshots[image]   [image]

Usage instructions are also available on the [website](http://www.mobomarket.net/tutorial/):

Unfortunately, I didn't use these personally but it is one of the recommended ones on XDA-[[PC][Windows] Android Free Universal PC Suites](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2355834)

I did recommend this one because it was one of the free alternatives, (but not implying is best among the given) you can give it a try, and it seems to accomplish what you want. There are far better android manager suites for pc but most of these are paid so I avoided these.

Comment: I do use this one, but get nervous that both WIndows and Android warn against installing it

Answer (score 1):

I tried MyPhoneExplorer (and others) but cannot see the benefit to just connecting your device, selecting MTP as transfer mode and then using plain Windows for copying the files you need to backup.

Comment: I have been using this for years. You can do backups etc. Also see description of features here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/sync-android-contacts-with-ms-outlook-contacts-without-a-cloud/50465#50465