# Sync Android Contacts with MS Outlook contacts without a cloud?

Tags: android, contact-manager, outlook

I want to sync Android Contacts with MS Outlook contacts. I don't want to put contacts into the cloud. Both devices are in the same `LAN`.

Answer (score 2):

Then you should take a look at **[MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client)** – which not only allows you to sync your contacts, but also your calendars and more cloud-lessly. Sync can be performed via WiFi, USB-Cable or Bluetooth. From the app description:

> - sync your contacts with Microsoft Outlook, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey, Lotus Notes, Tobit David, Windows Contacts,..
> - sync your calendar with Microsoft Outlook, Thunderbird, Sunbird, Lotus Notes, Tobit David, Windows Calendar,...
> - sync your notes with Microsoft Outlook, Lotus Notes and Windows StickyNotes
> - manage your SMS: download to PC, backup, delete, send SMS from desktop
> - view the call list of the phone, archive calls, delete them, backup call lists
> - sync file directories, copy files between desktop and phone, sync your photos
> - create and restore backups (includes contacts, calendar, tasks, notes, sms and files)
> - manage installed apps, launch, install, uninstall or download them to your desktop
> - control your phone through your desktop with mouse and keyboard, create screenshots
> - use the pc keyboard as input method for your phone
> - handle calls from your desktop, dial numbers, accept, reject and end calls

To use this, you will need the app and its desktop pendant. Both come for free.

Note: I'm in no way connected with FinjanSoft. I'm not even using Windows

Comment: Good choice. I have been using it for years now.