# Gratis Google-free contact manager for Android

Tags: gratis, android, contact-manager

I am looking for a gratis (at worst, sub $10) Contact Manager for Android.

It ***must*** be Google-free and must also not use me as a commodity. As such, I don’t want my contact data sitting on someone else’s servers.

- I want to be able to take my data with me when I move to a new Android. Possibly by storing the data on the Newer extended SIM file system, or by exporting it to SD card and re-importing on the new ‘phone.
- It would not hurt if there was a similar Windows program available, which understands the data format and can im/ex-port it.
- Rather than copy/paste I would want the app to allow me to select a contact (or their email address/’phone number) and choose to contact them by ‘phone/WhatsApp or Email (that’s all I use; other apps might be a bonus to others)

That’s about it, really : free or cheap, private and can launch contact apps

Comment: For that you can use the contacts app that ships with Android. You can export all your contacts via *Settings › Export* within this app. Then just turn off Google Sync in *Settings › Accounts* and you should be fine. If you insist on a separate app, be welcome to take a look into [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default contact manager that comes on android, you can use [MyPhoneExplorer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/sync-android-contacts-with-ms-outlook-contacts-without-a-cloud) app that can sync between your android phone and its desktop app and even your desktop MS Outlook. See the link for a previous detailed answer.

The default contact manager should allow you to select a contact and contact them by Phone/WhatsApp/Email.

Comment: But, can I keep that contact info away from Google?

Comment: Yes, I have been doing that for years.... But I do not set a google account on the phone. I think you can also choose what to sync with. Because I do not use a google account, I have to upgrade apps via other alternatives manually.